# Jenkins - Gitlab (https) connection

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to setup a connection between a Jenkins and GitLab server. The following error is displayed within a Pipeline:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h https://<url part 1>:<port><url part 2>.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: stderr: fatal: unable to access 'https://<url part 1>:<port><url part 2>.git/': Failed to connect to <url part 1> port <port>: Connection refused
```

I already tried to use the IP address and the domain name url. I checked the Jenkins questions and forums as well, but they don't seem to provide a solution. Most of the existing questions are using ssh, but I would like to use the https url.

Could you point me in the right direction, so I can solve the issue.

Comment: An incorrect configured server was causing the issue.

Comment: it is connection problem. if not solved still i can help.